# Need help in understanding how YOLO works?

Tags: computer-vision, yolo

In YOLO's [original paper](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Redmon_You_Only_Look_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf), I am quoting the parts I dont understand:

> Our system divides the input image into an S × S grid.
> If the center of an object falls into a grid cell, that grid cell
> is responsible for detecting that object.

> Each grid cell predicts B bounding boxes and confidence
> scores for those boxes. These confidence scores reflect how
> confident the model is that the box contains an object

- Are the different cells processed standalone? How the bounding boxes are determined by these small cells?
- Why the center of an object is responsible? The center cell of the object "Dog" in the example pic is probably a cell which has majority black pixels. It doesn't have any feature to help in any case.
- How the class probability map is calculated?

[image: official example image in the paper]

> Instead of the inception modules used by GoogLeNet, we
> simply use 1 × 1 reduction layers

- What are reduction layers? And 1x1 is just a number instead of a matrix. Is this number multiplied by all the layers?

Comment: part of your question can be answered by [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194142/what-does-1x1-convolution-mean-in-a-neural-network)